# Cannot run any windows WPF applications in windows XP SP3 SP2

Tags: .net, windows, frameworks, windows-xp

I have an application I am trying to deploy to several client computers.  The deployment went well to the primary computers.  But when I went to run the application on the secondary computers I the application crashed.  The computers are all Windows XP SP2 or SP3 VMs running inside VMWare.  When I first ran the application I got the message that the application required the .NET v4.0 framework.  I installed:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24872

After installation the application crashes as soon as it starts with the send error report dialog.  I tried making a blank WPF project in Visual studio 2012 - that crashes too.  I have tested both the blank application and the real application in other XP and win 7 VMs without an issue.  **When I try to run Windows forms applications they run fine - so it only effects WPF applications.**

When I check the even viewer I get 2 errors per startup crash:

```
Faulting application remoteclientapp.exe, version 1.0.0.0, stamp 532bee4b, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.1.2600.6293, stamp 506bc5e5, debug? 0, fault address 0x00012fd3.
```

And

```
Application: RemoteClientApp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Stack:
```

I have spent quite a lot of time repairing / installing .net frameworks.  I also did a virus scan with AVG on the target machine.  Does anyone have any leads for what the issue could be related to?

UPDATE

I used process monitor. I have found a few things like :

```
42:39.4 test.exe    3048    QueryOpen   C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\rsaenh.dll  NAME NOT FOUND
```

Is this related?  It seems like this dll would not be located here.  I have run the test app in both the working and not working environment here is the log comparison:

http://codeunity.net/logfile_compare.csv

Comment: You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to find out what missing file is causing the not found exception.

Comment: If you look at the lines from 808 onwards, Windows cannot find `System.Xaml.dll`.  Which led me to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7df6d95d-1a04-4a6f-b43d-3bab40d206dd/unable-to-run-wpf-application-in-windows-xp-computer?forum=wpf).  Which suggests that you need to ship `System.Xaml.dll` with your application.  It also suggests creating a setup package.  This is sensible, even if you don't intend to use it, because it will show you exactly what files you need.  Other posts suggest the file should be installed already.  Anyway, it's something to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, although it is in part a workaround.

We ended up compiling the application for the dotnet 3.5 framework. For some reason this was working on the client machine.  However we were still getting the data binding error described here

[A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435781/a-binding-can-only-be-set-on-a-dependencyproperty-of-a-dependencyobject)

I don't believe this data binding error was related, but it turned out to be a case of a bad character in the XAML when the 3.5 framework was targeted.

I should mention that the comment arx gave actually sounds related even though I was under the impression the XAML problem occurred after the change to dotnet 3.5.  If you have this issue you should consider trying 3.5 but also checking for XAML issues.